# Problems re-rendering a view with correct params when a user leaves form fields blank

Tags: grails, groovy

I am using a `noSelection` attribute in the `<g:select>` tag of the `Account` field for my `Load` `create` view.  When a user does not make a selection and clicks the "Create" button I expect the current values of all form fields to be passed to the `save` closure in my `Load` controller, which in turn re-calls the `create` view and populates that view with the previously mentioned current values.  This does not happen for two of my form fields and I am unclear why.

Here is what the `Load` `create` view called by the `/truckingmanagement/load/create` controller looks like:

[image]

If a user does not make a selection on in the `Account` field and then proceeds to click the "Create" button, a load obviously cannot be created.  Here is what the resulting `Load` `create` view called by the `/truckingmanagement/load/save` controller looks like:

[image]

**So I have two issues here, the first of which is that the `Logged By` field in the second view is not populated with the value selected in the first view.  Also, the drop down box is completely empty, there are no users to select from.  The second issue is that the `Account` field drop down box is completely empty, there are no accounts to select from.**

Here are the `<g:select>` tags used for the `Logged By` and `Account` fields in the `Load` `create` view.

`Logged By` field:

```
<g:select name="loggedBy.id" from="${loggedByUsers}" optionKey="id"  value="${loadInstance?.loggedBy?.id}" />
```

`Account` field:

```
<g:select id="account" name="account.id" from="${accountsWithCargoDestinations}" optionKey="id" noSelection="['':'-Select-']" />
```

Here are the `create` and `save` closures in my `LoadController`:

```
def create = {
    Role role1 = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
    Role role2 = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_OFFICE_PROFESSIONAL")
    Role role3 = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_DRIVER")   
    def loggedByUsers = UserRole.findAllByRoleInList([role1, role2, role3]).user

    def loadInstance = new Load()
    loadInstance.properties = params

    def accountsWithCargoDestinations = Account.findAllByUserInList(Address.findAll("from Address as addresses where addresses.cargoDestination=true").user)

    return [loadInstance:loadInstance, loggedByUsers:loggedByUsers, accountsWithCargoDestinations:accountsWithCargoDestinations]
}

def save = {
    def loadInstance = new Load(params)
    if (loadInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'load.label', default: 'Load'), loadInstance.id])}"
        redirect(action: "show", id: loadInstance.id)
    }
    else {
        System.out.println params //Trying to see if any values from the problem fields got lost.
        render(view: "create", model: [loadInstance: loadInstance])
    }
}
```

You will notice in the `println` statement in the `else` part of my `save` closure which prints out the `params`.  When I did this I found that the value selected in the `Logged By` field in the first view was indeed passed from the first view all the way to this point correctly, but I don't know why it is not displayed when the `Load` `create` view is rendered in the very next line of code, or at the least why *something* (i.e. `loggedByUsers` from the `truckingmanagement/load/create` controller) does not populate the `Logged By` field when the view is rendered.  Any help would be appreciated, and sorry for the verbosity.

Comment: I could be missing something simple here, but doesn't the model returned by your error happen to be missing loggedByUsers and accountsWithCargoDestinations?

Comment: @Joshua Moore, nope, you are not missing anything, but apparently I was, because that seems to have fixed it.  But for the sake of clean code, how / where do I place the `loggedByUsers` and `accountsWithCargoDestinations` definitions so I don't have to have the EXACT same code in two different closures (i.e. in the `create` AND in the `save` closure)?  I ask because just putting the mapping in the model of my `save` closure (as you suggested) does not do the trick, I had to copy the associated code from the `create` closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question posed in the comment response. You might want to investigate using [chain](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/chain.html) in your controller. You will need to re-work your create action a little to only instance a new loadInstance if not already present in the model. However, that should do the trick.

Comment: I read up on the `chain` method, but I actually went the route of writing a re-useable services instead... seemed to fit better. Now I can call my services from anywhere with only one line of code. I'll select your answer anyways because you did answer my question in the comment. Thanks again!