# Form values from the create view don't get passed to the save view

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

This question is an extension of / is similar too the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184409/problems-re-rendering-a-view-with-correct-params-when-a-user-leaves-form-fields-b).  The specific issue I was having in that question was solved, but I am having another very similar issue.

**The issue is that the "Cargo Destination" and "Cargo Source" values entered in the `create` view do not show up in the `save` view.**  For instance, when a user forgets to enter a necessary bit of information in the `create` view and presses the "Create" button, the values the user entered should show up in the `save` view.  All fields except the "Cargo Destination" and "Cargo Scource" show up in the `save` view when this scenario occurs.

When I put a `println` statement in my `save` controller, I can see that the parameters in question did indeed make it to the `save` controller from the `create` view.

The two fields in question are chained to other fields and populated by an AJAX that goes to a closure in the `Load` controller.  I *believe* this closure is where my problem is, in the `render` statement:

```
def getAccountUserCargoDestinations = {
    if(params.id == ""){
        render g.select(name: 'cargoDestination.id')
        return
    }
    def user = Account.find("from Account as account where account.id=:id", [id:Long.valueOf(params.id)]).user
    def addresses = Address.find("from Address as addresses where addresses.user=:user and addresses.cargoDestination=true", [user:user])
    render g.select(optionKey: 'id', from: addresses,  name: 'cargoDestination.id')
}
```

If that is not where the problem is, then it is probably in the corresponding field of the `create` view itself:

```
<g:select name="cargoDestination.id" optionKey="id" value="${loadInstance?.cargoDestination?.id}" />
```

**Two more things:**

1.) Grails is not giving me any errors

2.) A `cargoDestination` and a `cargoSource` are both instances of the `Address` class which I made.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Continuing to look for a solution I noticed several interesting things.  First I put the following code in my `create` view (which is rendered by the `create` closure in the Load controller, and re-rendered by the `save` closure in the Load controller IF the user leaves any fields blank):

```
  <g:if test="${loadInstance?.cargoDestination?.id != null}">
    ${loadInstance?.cargoDestination}
  </g:if>
```

By doing this I can see that the parameter is making it all the way to the `create` view when it is called by the `save` closure.  I guess I could use `<g:if> tags to get the desired results, but that just seems messy, and I doubt that is the "correct" way to solve this problem.  I also wrapped my AJAX in a similar``tag to make sure it was not changing the field value when the`save`closure rendered the`create`view, and I can confirm that the AJAX is indeed not changing the field value.  Other than the AJAX, the only thing different about my problem fields is that I do not have a`from`attribute in their corresponding`` tags (as can be seen by the code I posted originally in this question).  I know the solution is something simple... What am I missing here?

Comment: Unrelated - wtf is `Account.find("from Account as account where account.id=:id", [id:Long.valueOf(params.id)])`? Why not `Account.get(params.id)`?

Comment: @Burt Beckwith HAHA, apparently it is a much more complicated version of what you proposed. Thanks for the input, your code works the same and it is much cleaner :)  Any thoughts / ideas on my other problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out through process of elimination, but now that I see the solution it should have been very evident.

All I needed to do was add the `from` attribute to the affected `<g:select>` tags, like so:

```
<g:select from="${loadInstance?.cargoDestination}" name="cargoDestination.id" optionKey="id" value="${loadInstance?.cargoDestination?.id}" />
```

Works exactly as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

> The two fields in question are chained to other fields and populated
>   by an AJAX that goes to a closure in the Load controller.

hm. Is the object saved in between? It reads as if

- the data is sent to the `save` controller which does not save because there are missing fields
- the save controller displays the `save` view and `println`'s the field (which are available to the controller)
- the view invokes the `load` controller which tries to retrieve two fields from an object which isn't saved yet. There is no connection to the intermediate request data of the `save` controller.

if it's not this problem, I guess you'll have to post more code in order to get your problem analyzed.

hm. just taken a look at your other question. I see no chance for the Ajax `load` controller to get the data since the `save` controller did not persist the data to the database.

Why don't you output these values directly through the `save` view?

Comment: you are correct on your first point. On your second point, there is no save view (see code in other question). The save closure in the Load Controller calls the create view if a user leaves fields empty. The println statement was just for diagnostics. On your third point, if you look at the code in my previous question you will see that the create closure creates a new Load called loadInstance. When the user presses the "Create" button in the create view the save closure is called. The very first thing the save closure does is create a new loadInstance from the params passed to it.

Comment: The save closure creates a new `loadInstance`. Yes. But as far as I can see, it will not be saved to the database because the validation fails. The else part of the `if (x.save())` kicks and the `loadInstance` will be handed over to the view and then forgotten. How will the AJAX request get access to it?

Comment: You are correct about it not being saved to the database if validation fails, but the params are still there. The save closure renders the create view, and the model specified in the render method maps loadInstance. The AJAXs only comes into play initially to populate the select box in the create view. With this mapping, all the params entered in the create view are available (or should be) in the save view. It works correctly for every field except the two I have mentioned. All the params make it to the save closure correctly, but those two don't show up when the create view is re-rendered.